# Как добавить опцию сортировки товара, возвращающую стандартный способ сортировки?

Tags: modx, minishop2

Сайт работает на Modx, для создания каталога использовался miniShop2, для сортировки по параметрам используется msearch2

На сайте товар в каталоге сортируется по полю IDx (menuindex), так же присутствует возможность использовать сортировку по цене (по возрастанию и убыванию).

```
<span class="catalog-sub-nav__title">Сортировать по</span>
<select id="mse2_sort" class="sort__select">
<option value="asc" data-sort="ms|price">по возрастанию цены</option>
<option value="desc" data-sort="ms|price">по убыванию цены</option>
</select>
```

Однако, есть необходимость реализовать option "по умолчанию", выбор которого должен дать возможность вновь использовать сортировку по полю IDx, то есть стандартную. Как это сделать?

Comment: пустая опция не помогает вернуться к дефолтной сортировке?

Comment: <option>по умолчанию</option> и <option data-sort="" >по умолчанию</option> возвращают "no results found". Или я вас неправильно понял?